# Is it possible with Entity-Framework to apply all pending migrations TRANSACTIONALLY and rollback if any errors?

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server, entity-framework, linq-to-sql

Let's say I have migrations

```
Initial.cs
foo.cs
bar.cs
baz.cs
```

and my database is current "in sync" with applying

```
Initial.cs
foo.cs
```

and what I want to do is the equivalent of

```
Try applying bar.cs and then baz.cs, all in a transaction. If it fails, roll back.
```

Is that possible using `Update-Database` or `migrate.exe` with parameters or does it request special Powershell script or even custom C# logic?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think this is possible, but you can easily **revert** to a previous migration as EF allows that:

```
Update-Database -TargetMigration "PreviousMigrationIdentifer"
-ConnectionProviderName "System.Data.SqlClient" -Force
```

You can even use a **connection switch** to do that on Dbs having issues with migrations applied:

```
-ConnectionString "Data Source=(LocalDB)\Tests;Initial Catalog=DnbName;..."
```